# Swift2 - Error Handling on writeToFile

Tags: swift2

Questions:

1. How do I convert the following code to comply with Swift2 error
   handling.  I have been spending well over 2 days on this issue and
   have finally given up!
2. How would I call this in the viewDiDLoad?

Code:

```
func saveText(text: String, path: String) -> Bool {
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let status = text.writeToFile(path, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
    if !status { // status == false {
        print("Error saving file at path: \(path) with error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return status
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  func saveText(text: String, path: String) -> Bool {
    do {
      try text.writeToFile(path, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
      return true
    }
    catch {
      print("Error saving file at path: \(path) with error: \(error)")
    }
    return false
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if saveText("Hallo", path: "path-to-my-file") {
      print("Saved")
    } else {
      print("Failed")
    }
  }

}
```

---

Some resources for you ...

- [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

... in other words, it's much better when you do include your attempt (code) in the question, even not working. To show some effort, that you really tried to solve it. This question is not good from this point of view. It just says - I've got this in Swift 1.2, how to do in Swift 2. Also it helps understand your thinking and following answer can help you more then you think. Also you'll likely got your question answered. [Does Not Work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) is also very nice post.

Back to Swift 2. Keep in mind it's prerelease, it can contain bugs and sometimes not working code is not your fault. You should read:

- [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) - prerelease, about Swift 2.0, there's whole chapter about [Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508),
- [Swift - Resources](https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/) - playgrounds, more guides & docs,
- [Apple Swift Blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/) - blog written by Apple engineers, new features, changes, ... introduced there.

More advanced topics about Swift (blogs):

- [Airspeed Velocity](http://airspeedvelocity.net),
- [David Owens II](http://owensd.io),
- [Rob Napier](http://robnapier.net).

Also reserve some time to watch [WWDC 2015 - Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/), where you can learn a lot. Especially about new things.

And if you're lost, just search Stack Overflow or try to Google your problem. Because you're starting with Swift 2, there's a pretty good chance that your problem is already solved and someone blogged about it, answered question here, ...

Don't give up! As I wrote, it's fun. And if you think that your problem is big, unsolvable, so many things to do, just read [How do you eat an elephant?](http://importblogkit.com/2015/05/how-do-you-eat-an-elephant/)

Comment: Thanks Robert, you have made me look at the code a little different and I am understanding it so much better now.  I didn't know where to incorporate the "do" section.  I am learning and this was one of the issues that could have let me give-up, I was so frustrated.

Comment: Don't give up, programming is fun! :)

Comment: @ElizabethPiek just edited my answer and added some resources for you. What to read, where to learn, how to ask, ... Hope that helps and you don't quit :-)

Comment: I have to thank you for the support and I want to continue the learning.  The curve gets pretty steep at times but I am setting smaller goals with more research.  At times my biggest obstacle is my own mind, I need to learn how to think like a programmer and be very specific with setting my goals.